# Proportionality of parameter and mathematical expression

Tags: python, sympy, mathematical-expressions

What is the best way to check if a parameter increase in a mathematical expression increases or decreases the expression as a whole (in Python, preferably SymPy)?

Assumptions: all parameters are positive (i.e. > 0).

Example `A*B/(A+C)`: `A` should be found as proportional to the expression and `C` should be found as inverse proportional.

One obvious solution would be to assign 1 to all parameters, 1 and 100 to C respectively and apply `eval()`, but that is very crude and might yield errors (e.g. with `(A-B)/C` where the best case would be to give an error instead of a wrong result).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this can be solved in the general case.  A simple  counter-example is `sin(A)`, which could be both proportional and inverse proportional, depending on what value of A you are evaluating it at.

However, you could use an automatic differentiation tool, such as PyDX or Theano, to compute the derivative of functions at various parameter values.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Differentiation is a nice idea, but then I'd prefer numerical methods as they are way less computationally expensive.

Comment: For one-shot computation, yes.  If you're going to be testing a single function at multiple parameter values, AD is probably just as efficient.

Comment: True, but: in my case I only need to test each expression once ;-) Any recommendation for a tool that does this as a one-liner?